# How to initialize AspectJ aspect without using a constructor?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

My AspectJ aspect looks like this:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  private Child child;
  public MyAspect() {
    this.child = new Child();
  }
  @Around("... skipped ...")
  public Object wrap(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    // some custom functionality
    return point.proceed();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because during the construction of `Child` a `wrap()` pointcut gets called and it leads to a runtime exception, since an instance of `MyAspect` is not yet ready.

Is it possible to tell AspectJ somehow to call some method of `MyAspect` right after its instantiating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New answer:**

Here is a sample driver class `Child`:

```java
public class Child {
    private String name;

    public Child(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Constructing child named " + this.name);
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child myChild = new Child("Penélope");
        System.out.println("My child is named " + myChild.getName());
        myChild.setName("María Elena");
        System.out.println("My child is now named " + myChild.getName());
    }
}
```

And here is an aspect `MyAspect` intercepting public method and constructor executions of `Child`, but excluding the aspect constructor:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    private Child child;

    public MyAspect() {
        child = new Child("Scarlett");
        System.out.println("Aspect child is named " + child.getName());
        child.setName("Cristina");
        System.out.println("Aspect child is now named " + child.getName());
    }

    @Around(
        "(execution(public * Child.*(..)) || execution(public Child.new(..)))" +
        "&& !cflow(initialization(MyAspect.new()))"
    )
    public Object wrap(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(point.getStaticPart());
        return point.proceed();
    }
}
```

This is the sample output:

```
Constructing child named Scarlett
Aspect child is named Scarlett
Aspect child is now named Cristina
execution(void Child.main(String[]))
execution(Child(String))
Constructing child named Penélope
execution(String Child.getName())
My child is named Penélope
execution(void Child.setName(String))
execution(String Child.getName())
My child is now named María Elena
```

You can see that no `Child` joinpoints are intercepted during aspect construction. BTW, otherwise you would get `NoAspectBoundException` anyway. `;-)`

---

**Old answer:**

You can combine your pointcut with something like (untested):

```
... && !cflow(MyAspect.new())
```

Ths should exclude what you do not want intercepted.

Comment: nope, doesn't filter out my initialization flow (actual syntax, I believe, is `!cflow(initialization(MyAspect.new()))`)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. That's the problem about writing untested (as I said!) answers on iPad. Anyway, if it led you on the right track, it was not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are best off trying to do the initialization inside of an advice.  Eg-

```
after() : execution(MyAspect.new()) {
  this.child = new Child();
}
```

But really, this strikes me as bad form. Having advice of the containing aspect being applied somewhere during the construction of `Child` seems like a circular dependency.  I'd try to refactor (perhaps into multiple aspects) in order to avoid the circularity.

Comment: this approach leads to the same circularity problem, since this new pointcut (as any other pointcut) requires an already instantiated object of class `MyAspect`

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but since this is after executing advice, the instantiation should already be complete.  You could also try changing execute to call (but be careful since the semantics are different).